# JS hide function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 7 different DIV blocks. 
The first DIV block should appear at the beginning, be hiding the other. 
For that I gave `display: none` block at the other six defined. 
So the other block should appear, I have a JS code copied from the internet.

```
 function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('.newboxes').each(function (index) {
         if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
             $(this).show();
         }
         else {
             $(this).hide();
         }
     }); 
}
```

Problem is, I become an Error from Firebug:

RefernceError: showonlyone is not defined

I hope, I have declared you all right.

Comment: Please just learn Javascript instead of posting questions on SO about errors you don't understand in code you copy/pasted from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load the js at the beginning of the dom, else the function wont be declared.

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) { 
   $('.newboxes').each(function () { 
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) { 
         $(this).show(); 
      } else { 
         $(this).hide(); 
      }
   }); 
}
```

Also you can enhance the whole function to this:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) { 
   $('.newboxes:not([data-id='+thechosenone+'])').hide();
  $('.newboxes[data-id='+thechosenone+']').show();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The code you have is a perhaps a little complicated. Something like this:

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $(".newboxes").hide();
    $("#"+thechosenone).show();
}
```

would be much simpler.

As for the function being undefined, make sure the function is defined in a scope that can be reached by the thing calling it!